# How we can get selected text start off set with respect to his parent element in java script?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I'm facing some problem in using javascript.The scenario is like html object has one parent element paragraph and 4 child element span . when we select text we are getting text position with respect to span element , but i want to get text selecting text with respect to parent so can you please guide me how i can?
I'm using this code that each time give position with respect to selected container like

```
<p>I'm using this code that each time<span>give position with respect to selected container like</span></html>
```

i want to get text position " respect" on upper code with respect to p tag not with repect to span tag.

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
    var selRange      = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var start         = selRange.startContainer;
    var startElemPath = pathOfElement(start);
    var startoff      = selRange.parentNode.startOffset;
    alert("startoff>>"+startoff);
    var end           = selRange.endContainer;
    var endElemPath   = pathOfElement(end);
    var endoff        = selRange.endOffset;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this process to get start off set and end off set of selected text.

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(objectId, win)
{
    var startOffSet = 0;
    var endOffset = 0;
    var element = window.frames[0].document.getElementById(objectId);
    var parentInnerHTML = element.innerHTML.toString();
    var parentNodeArr = parentInnerHTML.split('');
    if(parentInnerHTML != "null"){
        var sel;
        if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined")
        {       
            var rangeIndex = 0; 
            var parentIndex = 0;
            var max = parentInnerHTML.length - 1;
            var range = win.getSelection().toString();
            var rangeNodeArr = range.split('');
            var rangeLen = rangeNodeArr.length - 1;
            for (parentIndex=0; parentIndex <= max; parentIndex++)
            {
                if(parentNodeArr[parentIndex] === rangeNodeArr[rangeIndex]){
                    if(rangeIndex === rangeLen){
                        break;
                    }
                    rangeIndex++;
                }else{
                     rangeIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            endOffset = parentIndex + 1;
            startOffSet = parentIndex - rangeIndex;
        }
        console.log("startOffSet: " + startOffSet + " endOffset: " + endOffset);
        return { startOffSet: startOffSet, endOffSet: endOffset };
    }else{
        console.log("Parent is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with this solution which is the fact if you highlight a word that has multiple instances it only returns the first instance start/end points.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `Range`'s start node to `p`

```
startNode = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
selRange.setStart(startNode,0);
```